# WHERE at least one of multiple columns in date range

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with columns ID, DATE1, DATE2, DATE3 , DATE4. I can get the results I need using the following quesry:

```
Select ID from table 
WHERE ((DATE1 >= '2020-01-01' AND DATE1 <= '2020-31-01') 
   OR (DATE2 >= '2020-01-01' AND DATE2 <= '2020-31-01') 
   OR (DATE3 >= '2020-01-01' AND DATE3 <= '2020-31-01') 
   OR (DATE4 >= '2020-01-01' AND DATE4 <= '2020-31-01') )
```

So as you can see what I need is a list of ID where at least one of the date columns (DATE1, DATE2, DATE2, DATE4) is carrying a date in Jan 2020.

The query that I wrote works just fine but I am wondering if there is a smarter way of writing that query so that I need to provide the date range only once?

Not sure if it matters but if it does I am running DB2.

Comment: I don't think there is any better way to write this query.

Comment: Why not use placeholders?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can improve your query imho is using placeholders as @Jeff Holt mentioned.
But it won't change the executed SQL in the end.

Another possibility (but that totally depends on your requirements) is seperating the 'id' from the date columns and use a 1:N relation.

For example an activity that can occur on multiple dates:

```
table `activity`
-------------
| id | name |
|--- | ---- |
| 1  |tennis|
-------------
```

```
table `activity_planned`
-----------------------------
| id |activity_id|   date   |
|----|-----------|----------|
| 1  | 1         |2020-02-08|
| 2  | 1         |2020-02-12|
| 3  | 1         |2020-02-11|
| 4  | 3         |2020-03-01|
-----------------------------
```

That way you can also easily add more dates than just 4.

Answer (score 2):

Using placeholders, query factoring, and the between operator (in your specific case you're including both ends of the time intervals), you can make the pixels tighter and easier to read.

```
with dates (begin_date, end_date) as
    (select ?, ? from dual)
Select ID
from table t join dates d
WHERE
    (t.DATE1 between d.begin_date AND d.end_date) OR
    (t.DATE2 between d.begin_date AND d.end_date) OR
    (t.DATE3 between d.begin_date AND d.end_date) OR
    (t.DATE4 between d.begin_date AND d.end_date)
```